# Pulling a bead constrained to move along a frictionless rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Suppose a bead is constrained to move along a horizontal rod and is pulled by a light string at constant speed $v_s$. At a given instant, the string makes an angle $θ$ with the horizontal and is being pulled at a speed $v_s$, taking the speed of the bead $v_b$, the standard result is often given as $v_b=v_s/cosθ$. I don't understand why we don't take $v_b=v_scosθ$, afterall it is more natural to say that the velocity of the bead is the horizontal component of the velocity of the string (the component of the velocity of the string along the road) than vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't do so, because the velocity of the bead is not just due to the x component of the string velocity, but the y component contributes to it as well. The approach is that the component of velocities along the string must be equal, for the string is light and inextensible. This yields the desired condition.
Mathematically, let the origin be at one end of the horizontal rod. Let the position of the bead be $(x_1,0)$ and that of the other end of the string be $(x_2,h)$ where h is the vertical height below the rod. Now, you have a right triangle with vertices $(x_1,0),(x_1,h),(x_2,h)$ with the string length l as the hypotenuse. Now, by Pythagoras' theorem, $l^2=h^2+(x_2-x_1)^2.$ Differentiating both sides, remembering that $\frac{dh}{dt}=v_ssin\theta,\frac{dx_2}{dt}=v_scos\theta,$ and $\frac{dx_1}{dt}=v_b,$ and of course,$\frac{dl}{dt}=0$ (I followed your terminology for velocities, and $\theta$ is the angle between string and horizontal.) and substituting these values yields the correct answer, $v_b=v_s/cos\theta.$

Comment: In what way does the y component of the velocity of the string contribute to the velocity of the bead?

Comment: That's what I stated mathematically above.. physically, I think we can picture it this way: bot the x component and y component of the string will have a velocity along the string, right? So, the inextensibility of the string means that the bead velocity must also adjust to the y component's component along the string, otherwise the string will no longer be tight.

Comment: "both the x component and y component of the string will have a velocity along the string", what did you mean by this?

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was that the velocity of the string can change depending on both it's x and y components, so there should be a corresponding change in bead velocity as well... And in general for constraint problems, the velocities along the string must be equal, which amounts to saying that the string length is fixed.